# Is there a reason to have a separate id primary key if I already have an unique key?

Tags: python, sql, database, primary-key, flask-sqlalchemy

Say I'm working with Steam users, each has an unique [SteamID](https://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/SteamID). Do I still need a separate `id` column to act as a primary key, or can I just use the SteamID? I.e. is this enough (using [Flask-SQLAlchemy](http://flask-sqlalchemy.pocoo.org/2.1/)):

```
class User(db.Model):
    steamid = db.Column(db.String(20), primary_key=True, unique=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(120))
    # more stuff
```

Or should I still include an unique `id` as seen in [Flask-SQLAlchemy's examples](http://flask-sqlalchemy.pocoo.org/2.1/quickstart/):

```
class User(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    steamid = db.Column(db.String(20), unique=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(120))
    # more stuff
```

And if so, **why**?

Comment: The main argument against it would be performance, integer primary keys are usually faster to query and work with.

Comment: If that's really the main reason and there's no (real) functional difference, I wouldn't mind you post that as an answer @FranciscoCouzo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main argument against it would be performance, integer primary keys are usually faster to query and work with.

It's mainly a matter of preference, if indexing by `steamid` makes more sense and is easier to reason about I'd go for it, since the performance difference won't be really big.

Answer (score 1):

While it's true that a numeric value for an ID value is a little faster to sort and locate by the system, the difference is unlikely to be noticeable or even measurable.

The problem is, you don't say what a *steam* is or the role it plays in your system. Apparently, though, there is a 1-1 relationship between it and each user. So why not just call it *ID* in the User table and alias it as needed to *UserID* or *SteamID* depending on which makes more sense in the context the user happens to be in at the time.

When using a surrogate key, my preference it to call it ID. Short, simple, unambiguous. When looking at the definition of a table, it says, "I'm the surrogate key of this table." There is really no confusing it when using the same field of several tables in the same query. In fact, it helps to clarify:

```
select User.ID, Item.ID, Entry.ID, etc.
from ....
```

However, the query establishes the context of the result set. Aliasing helps in showing that context:

```
select User.ID as ManagerID, Item.ID OfficeOD, Entry.ID LaptopID, etc.
from ....
```

When using it as a FK in another table, the name in that table would also show its use in the context established by that table. This is especially handy if several fields are FKs to the same table:

```
table Accounts: 
  ID         the surrogate key to this table...duh!
  OwnerID    references User.ID
  AdminID    references User.ID
  VerifiedBy references User.ID
```

or perhaps

```
table Accounts: 
  ID         the surrogate key to this table...duh!
  SteamID    references User.ID
  AdminID    references User.ID
  VerifiedBy references User.ID
```

Comment: I suppose this would work fine, but what's the difference between calling it `id` or `steamid` if it does the same thing anyways? *"you don't say what a steam is or the role it plays in your system"* oh the first mention of SteamID actually links to Valve's page which explains SteamID in full: https://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/SteamID

Comment: Didn't read the entire linked page, but it appears your system maintains the same name over many different contexts. This could be more confusing than changing the name to fit the context. A developer who saw "OwnerID" in a table definition would also see in the FK that it references User table and immediately know the correlation. The definition of "OwnerID" in different a table that references the Accounts table would clarify *that* correlation. I've edited my answer to give more detail.

Answer (score 0):

For most cases the SteamID should be sufficient. It could be problematic if the ID's are close and the difference is a space in the ID or something of that sort. Using the uniqueId's is really the best way.